# iText HTML with embedded CSS

Tags: java, html, export, itext

I'm working on a table export interface to export to HTML, PDF and RTF. I'm using iText for this because it allows very similar handling of the three types.

Simple example for HTML export:

```
final Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
HtmlWriter writer = HtmlWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
Table actTable = new Table(colCount);
final Cell c = new Cell(cellString);

c.setColspan(colSpan);
c.setHeader(isHeader);

actTable.addCell(c);
writer.add(actTable);
```

The base version is working so far and I want to style the elements now.

In the former export class I used an embedded stylesheet:

```
  String cssFileContent = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("style.css"));

  final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  sb.append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\">\n");
  sb.append("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'>\n");
  sb.append("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n");
  sb.append("<head>\n<title>");
  sb.append(title);
  sb.append("</title>\n");
  sb.append("<style media='screen' type='text/css'>\n");
  sb.append(cssFileContent); // embed the stylesheet
  sb.append("</style>");
  sb.append("<div id=\"header\"></div>\n");
  sb.append("</head>\n");
  sb.append("<body>\n");
  ...
```

Now I am trying to add a style element with iText but can not figure out how to do that. Please help!

My second question: How can I prevent iText from creating a `div` tag for every cell?

```
<tr>
  <td border="0.5" width="0">
    <div>testA0,0
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should **NOT** use old versions of iText. On top of technical limitations, there are some serious legal issues with pre-5 versions of this lib : http://lowagie.com/iText2 . Starting with iText 5, the RTF functionnality has been removed (which I understand could be a problem for you), but the HTML-to-PDF conversion has been significantly improved.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I can abandon RTF support, it was just a nice-to-have. But for clearance: this is not about HTML-to-PDF. The topic is about HTML export in general.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I was too quick in reading your question... iText 5+ won't do any HTML export I fear, its scope has been narrowed to its initial purpose : PDF creation and manipulation.

Comment: Yes. I will use iText 5 and look out for a new stream based (without DOM tree) HTML export api.